# MVC VS 2012 - Insert to single table while using ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, entity-framework

I began with the following tables; one for staff names, and one for salutations:

```
public class PrmTbl_Salutation
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public PrmTbl_Salutation(int id, string desc, Boolean active)
    {
        ID = id;
        Desc = desc;
        Active = active;
    }

    public PrmTbl_Salutation() { }
}

public class PrmTbl_Staff
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int SalutationID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public PrmTbl_Staff(int id, int salID, string name, Boolean active)
    {
        ID = id;
        SalutationID = salID;
        Name = name;
        Active = active;
    }

    public PrmTbl_Staff() { }
    public PrmTbl_Salutation Salutation { get; set; }

}
```

I had individual Views for each table, but wanted to combine them so that a staff name would be preceded by their relevant salutation. The View would include an editable list of current staff as a form, with another form to insert a new staff record. This is the ViewModel:

```
public class StaffSalutation
{
    public int StaffID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Salutation { get; set; }
    public int SalutationID { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public List<PrmTbl_Salutation> SaltsList { get; set; }
}
```

The update functionality works fine:

```
PrmTbl_Staff thisRow = staffDB.PrmTbl_Staffs.Find(id);

string tempName = Convert.ToString(UpdateArray[thisName]);
Boolean tempActive = Boolean.Parse(UpdateArray[thisActive]);
int tempSalID = Convert.ToInt32(UpdateArray[thisSalID]);

thisRow.Name = tempName;
thisRow.Active = tempActive;
thisRow.SalutationID = tempSalID;

staffDB.SaveChanges();
```

... but the insert fails

```
string tempName = Convert.ToString(staff["name"]);
int tempSalID = Convert.ToInt32(staff["saltID"]);
PrmTbl_Staff thisRecord = new PrmTbl_Staff(0, tempSalID, tempName, true);
staffDB.PrmTbl_Staffs.Add(thisRecord); //FAILS HERE
staffDB.SaveChanges();
return RedirectToAction("Staff");
```

with the error `The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.PrmTbl_Staff_dbo.PrmTbl_Salutation_SalutationID". The conflict occurred in database "LibraryBase2.DAL.LibraryContext", table "dbo.PrmTbl_Salutation", column 'ID'.
The statement has been terminated.`

This is my first time using ViewModels. There appears to be an ambiguity or conflict regarding the Salutation ID and the new Staff ID. What am I doing wrong? Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using entity framework? If so, please add `ef` tag.

Comment: @Mahmoodvcs What do you mean the `ef` tag? I'm using a Data Access Layer, separate to the Models themselves, if that's what you mean...?

Comment: I mean question tags. So we can better understand question's context. Never mind. I did it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are setting `SalutationID` with a value that doesn't exist in database. besides, are you sure that the error is happening in `Add` line. usually Entity framework rises these errors when calling `SaveChanges` method.

Comment: Good call, I used a breakpoint to see that there was a null value attempting to be inserted as the salutation ID due to me mis-labelling the submitted array key in the controller. (And the error was on the SaveChanges call also :) ). Its a simple fix, but not until you know what you're looking for! Thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 0):

The conflict is between the salutationID assigned and the salutation IDs in the salutation table.  You have a constraint set up saying you can not insert a staff record with a salutation ID that does not exist in the salutation table.

Put a breakpoint on the line that is failing and check the value of tempSalID, and compare that to the values in the table.

Either the constraint needs to be removed, or you need to add a new record to the salutation table before adding a record to the staff table when this condition exists.

Comment: Thanks KennyZ. You and Mahmoodvcs were both correct - thanks for the help :)